# double for-loop to calculate the mean in a range of rows in a matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, vector

```
dataset <- matrix(rnorm(100), 20, 5)
```

My dataset is a matrix of 100 returns, of 5 assets over 20 days.
I want to caluclate the average return for each asset, between 1:10 rows and 11:20 rows.
Then, I want to include the returns so computed in two vectors, in turn, included in a list.

The following list should include the two vectors of returns computed between rows 1:10 and 11:20.

```
returns <- vector(mode="list", 2)
```

I have implemented a for-loop, as reported below, to calculate the mean of returns only between 1:10.

```
assets <- 5
r <- rep(0, assets) # this vector should include the returns over 1:10
for(i in 1:assets){
  r[i] <- mean(data[1:10,i])
}
returns[[1]] <- r
```

How could I manage this for-loop in order to calculate also the mean of returns between 11:20 rows?

I have tried to "index" the rows of the dataset, in the following way.

```
time <- c(1, 10, 11, 20)
```

and then implement a double for-loop, but the length are different. Moreover, in this case, I meet difficulties in managing the vector "r". Because, in this case, I should have two vectors and no longer only one as before.

```
for(j 1:length(time){
    for(i in 1:assets){
      r[i] <- mean(data[1:10,i])
    }}
    returns[[1]] <- r
```

Comment: did it work? Do you need a solution with the loop?

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you, for your answer. If it is not a problem, I would like to see also the code with the for-loop.

Comment: Because here a make a simpler example, but in my dataset I have more rows. So, I'm also interested in a for-loop. @RafaelC

Comment: Just edited my answer! Take a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need a `for` loop. You can use `colMeans`

```
returns <- vector(mode="list", 2) 
returns[[1]] <- colMeans(dataset[1:10,])
returns[[2]] <- colMeans(dataset[11:20,])
```

---

Using a `for` loop, your solution could be something like the following

```
for(i in 1:assets){
  returns[[1]] <- c(returns[[1]], mean(dataset[1:10,i]))
  returns[[2]] <- c(returns[[2]], mean(dataset[11:20,i]))
}
```